# Oracle Database: the order of a query result

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Suppose there is a table with columns: Id (primary key), myTime, myName

and you execute the query:

```
select * from mytable order by myTime
```

But there are several entries with the same value in myTime. Which order is used to arrange the results? I´ve tried this example on several machines, and the results are different. The results with the same value of myTime are ordered differently depending of the machine (although both machines use the same version of Oracle DDBB 10g).

Thanks.

Comment: The order is unpredictable, as you've noticed.

Comment: Oracle do what you ask : order by mytime. so if two values have the same mytime you can't guess which one will be sorted before or not. If you want to have a sort that fit better your need you have to change something.

Comment: Yes, I ordered it also by the myName column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order will depend on the access method of the table, and possibly the sort algorithm, but in general (not always, I'd think) what you'll see is that the implicit sort order will be by rowid if an index has been used to provide the sort order. If a full scan and sort are used then I'd not like to guess.

If a deterministic sort order is required, add an order by primary key, or a unique key. A secondary sort order of ROWID would possibly be helpful in some situations where you have an application that paginates.

Comment: `implicit sort order will be by rowid` - most probably not (there are a lot other access paths that will result in completely different "orders". Ordering by ROWID is a very bad idea - for paging you should use an `order by` combined with `rownum` or `row_number()`

Comment: "... by rowid if an index has been used to provide the sort order", because indexes order rows of the same value by rowid so that is likely to be how they are returned. That aside, ordering by rowid is only handy in situations where short-term stability in the sort order is required, as when an application relies on deterministic sort order for correct pagination.